# Drawing the Zipf distribution

Tags: r, math

I have a dataset with zipf law distribution, and now i want compare it with standard `zipf` diagram, this is my `R` code:

```
f <- read.table('/myfile.txt',sep='\t',header=T)
attach(f)
fs <- f[order(cnt), ]
detach(f)
n = 1:dim(fs)[1]
plot(fs[,2]~n)
```

Now i want to compare it with `zipf` in the same plot, How can i do this in `R`?

Comment: How about something like

`N = 10; s=0.5; y = 1:N
proby = dzipf(y, N=N, s=s)
lines(y, proby, type="l")
`

Of course, you'll have to adjust the parameter to suit your case

Comment: Yes that must work for me but i cannot run it in `R`, i get `Error: could not find function "dzipf"`

Comment: it is in the `VGAM` library, you have to attach that first.

Comment: Why not use the zipfR package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The VGAM package has facilities for estimating the exponent in the Zipf distribution. You might want to plot your distribution against a best fit estimated density:

```
plot( cntdens <- table(f[['cnt']])/length(f[['cnt']]),
       xlim=range(f[['cnt']]), ylim=c(0, 0.8)  )

# And then plot the theoretic distribution for the VGAM fit 
# ... extending the example on ?VGAM::zipf:

require(VGAM)
zdata <- data.frame( y=1:max( f[['cnt']] ),  ofreq= table( f[['cnt']] ) )
fit = vglm(y ~ 1, zipf, zdata, trace = TRUE, weight = ofreq, crit = "coef")
proby = dzipf(1:max(f[['cnt']]), N =max(f[['cnt']]), s = Coef(fit) )
points((1:5)+0.05, proby,  col="red")
```

Below is that procedure using the data in the example on the ?dzipf page.
[image]

Comment: I install `zipfR` package and `lobrary(zipfR)`, then i run your code but i get `Error: could not find function "dzipf"`.

Comment: That because  ... as my code implies ... dzipf in my session was from the VGAM package, not the zipfR package.